# Proteus component not working

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, proteus

I'm trying to simulate an L2577-adj circuit in Proteus software but I can't find it in the local library that come with Proteus.

I could, however, find it in [component search engine](https://componentsearchengine.com/) ,
but after downloading the files and importing them with Proteus they show up, but I get no model specified error.

I found out that if I mark the checkbox attach hierarchy module it should work, and that's what happened: the simulation works but the item that I imported does not work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing from Component Search Engine only imports up to 3 parts. Schematic model, PCB footprint and 3D model. Neither of which have the SPICE files that Proteus accepts. So you won't be able to simulate imported models.

You can either go to the Proteus forums and request the part, or you can find a similar one, adjust the properties and save as a new device, or you can create a new one from scratch.